# Eclipse: On Save execute a program

Tags: eclipse

I have recently come across the [LESS Leaner CSS](http://lesscss.org/) a template engine for CSS based on ruby. The idea sounded neat, but in practice we need to compile the program to get CSS. This is cumbersome as we make too many changes while working on CSS and for every edit we don't want to compile.

In Eclipse, there are "Save-Actions" but it handles only formatting changes.

Is there a way on saving the file in Eclipse, to call or trigger the compilation?

Its easy to do this in Vi or Emacs.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think all you need is to define a custom Builder for your project. That way, you can run a program or an ant script whenever certain files change.

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Builders -> New

Comment: Perfect. Never used this feature.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360596/eclipse-auto-build-after-save/3360636#3360636 for more slightly detailed instructions (with screen shots).

Comment: I explained, how you set up a builder that compiles your less automatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686281/unnoticeable-lesscss-compiler-in-eclipse-pdt/9577888#9577888

Answer (score 10):

While the Builders are a good solution, keep in mind they only work when a build is issued - either using auto-build or using a manual build which is invoked, well, manually. If you are looking for something that will operate after a save, regardless of the auto-build state you will need to write a plugin which listens to resource changes in Eclipse.

You do that by creating a workspace change listener and installing it like that:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(
..., IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE);
```

I'm sure you can take it from here :-)

Comment: Does anyone know if there is already a plug-in that does this?  Not being a Java programmer, (use Eclipse for HTML/JS/XML) writing a plug-in is not my preferred course of action.

Comment: I used Eclipse (Luna version) to compile SCSS to CSS when a file in a specific folder changes and I didn't need to write a plugin. With the sole configuration was enough. I checked "During auto builds" in Build options pane and I specified the working set of relevant resources in order to run the program the fewer times, the better.