# eclipse: auto build after save

Tags: eclipse, ant, build

I have an ant script that creates runnable jar and I want it to run each time I make changes in my code and save them. I guess I need some "auto build after save" option in Eclipse. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could declare your script as a builder, and make it run "`during auto build`".

[image: Launch configuration properties]

See the properties of your project: you can add an external program (above) or an an script (below).

[image: Target]

If you can export your script as an ant script, like the [OP David B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377031/david-b) did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3360884/6309), it becomes quite easy:

1. **Export as an ant script**: right-click the `project -> export -> runaable jar file`, tick "`save as ANT script`" and <kbd>finish</kbd>.
2. **Add the ant script as a builder**: right-click the `project -> properties -> Builders -> new (Ant)`.
   Paste the path for the ant file, go to "`targets`" tab and click the "`set targets`" button next to "`auto build`".
   Finally, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: I like the screenshots, which app did you use?

Comment: @zengr: [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), see comments of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the best solution I found was: right-click the project -> export -> runaable jar file, tick "save as ANT script" and finish. Now right-click the project -> properties -> Builders -> new -> paste the path for the ANT file, go to "targets" tab and click the "set targets" button next to "auto build", OK, OK, OK.

Comment: Good point. I have included your process next to the screenshot of the ant builder in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use an ANT file which will be triggered everytime you save a file: [Using Ant to Auto-Build in Eclipse](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65486.html)