# Eclipse to run android application on save

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, adt

I will have a lot of UI work to do, some of it in code behind where the 'Graphical Layout' pane in eclipse cannot help me. It is likely I will have to deploy the code a lot in order to get everything visually perfectly aligned.

I'd like to tune eclipse so that it will trigger automatic run on the device on each save I do.

I'd like my workflow to be
-modifying code
-saving
-looking away to device to see the differences.

Please tell me this CAN be done.

Comment: not sure. but you can do is auto-save each time you run.

Comment: Even if this works as you wont, you still have to wait for the deployment of your application to the avd or real device, if it's the avd you are deploying to the it will not be that instant as you would like and in this case I don't see why you would just press another button to deploy in, in any case you are going to wait.

Comment: "'Graphical Layout' pane in eclipse cannot help me" is this *really* true?

Comment: I know it will not be instant. Another related problem I have is that I cannot use the run keyboard shortcut when I am dealing with layout files, and I have to reach for the mouse and click on the run menu and... well it's not the biggest problem in the world, but I hope to minimize its impact.

Comment: Simon, pretty much. There are some code behind transformations on the UI that are not reflected when looking at the 'Graphical Pane'. At least I am not familiar with a way to able to see what it will look like. That's one of the bad things when partial dealing with layouts in code rather than xml.

Comment: @George why can't you use your keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Indeed. Ctrl + S to save and ctrl + f11 to run. With the correct run configuration it will be installed on all attached devices and running emulators...

Comment: @WarrenFaith, part of the issue, whenever I am editing a layout file (an xml), ctrl + f11 (command-shift-f11 on my case) does not run compile/run the app. The shortcut works perfectly when I edit java code though.

Comment: Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching and then check the "Launch Operation" to "Always launch the previously launched application" this should to the trick

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could achive this by a custom Builder. Right click your project -> `Preferences` -> `Builders` -> `New` -> `Program`. Try to run either a run configuration or write a script which starts the deployment and use it here. 
Is it possible to deploy to a device by Maven? Then this would be a better option for your own builder (choose `New` -> `Maven Build`).

Comment: This could work really work. However for this project there are CDT builder, android resource manager, android precompiler, java builder, package builder and so on. And they are non-editable. My point is that it won't be quite trivial to figure the exact build steps these make and simulate them via a build script :( . I was hoping more for a way to invoke on save whatever eclipse does when it launches a run configuration. There's got to be a way to do this!

Comment: @George You don't have to. Just add a script which deploys the `.apk` file to the device as last builder. All real building is done before by the builders you have mentioned! They run in the order they are listed.

Comment: does it happen on auto build? We have some C code and there's quite a log when it gets recompiled, and this doesn't happen whenever I save a file, only when I click on the run button :( P.S. I don't need it to recompile the C, just not sure whether it does rebuild the .apk on save!

Comment: Is `Project` -> `Build Automatically` checked? Then eclipse builds on save. But I don't know about your C stuff to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a Builder system, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360596/eclipse-auto-build-after-save/3360636#3360636).

I created a new Builder program,  and created a small .bat file that installs my apk
. Also checked the "Build option" Launchin background and "During auto builds".

My script that is being called looks like this;

```
adb install -r c:\dev\myapp.apk
adb shell am start -n com.company.exampleapp/com.company.exampleapp.ExampleApp
```

Comment: Turns out that the ADT does not run the integrated non-editable builders on save... Doing what u suggest uploads the old .apk, I cannot see any changes unfortunately. I can see them whenever I run it the normal way.

Comment: Hum, tried "specify working set of relevant resources" in Build options menu?

Comment: I did, it didn't affect the outcome - still redeploying the old .apk. This is odd, the new builder is at the end of the list and there is certainly _some_ stuff happening on save, I just think the apk repackaging is left out.

Comment: Can build apk with ant build and then run above to put apk in emulator maybe?