# Eclipse: Export .JAR on save

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to export a project every time I make changes to it, but going through the menus `Right click -> Export... -> JAR File -> Next -> Finish` is annoying an a bit time consuming.

I heard you could somehow make Eclipse automatically export when saving, I searched everywhere but I didn't find anything, I'd like to know how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is:

1) Create an Ant script to compile your Java and export your .jar

2) Configure an Eclipse "Build" script to invoke Ant each file save.

Here are two links that tell you how:

- [eclipse: auto build after save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360596/eclipse-auto-build-after-save)
- http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65486.html

Here's an excellent, brief tutorial for getting started with Ant:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html

Comment: Alright, I'm new to this, I made an Ant script that builds a .JAR file like I want, I created the run configuration... And I think I did something wrong, I have "Build automatically" turned on, I have the Ant script as the only builder, but when I save nothing happens... It's not a problem with the build script since it works if ran as `Right Click -> Run As -> Ant Build`