# Automatic EOL conversion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, line-endings

Need to keep EOL format consistent in all resources under Eclipse workspace.

I know about Eclipse preference that sets new line style for newly created files, but I would like to have automatic conversion for already existing files. Is there some settings/plugins?

**I want just setup once and be sure that all line endings are in the same format.**

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In addition to the **Window > Preferences > General > Workspace** setting for new files that you already know about, there is a **File > Convert Line Delimiters To** option.  I don't know of any existing plugin/tool that will do this **automatically** when you save, but you could certainly write one or make converting the line ending part of your process.

To make it easier on yourself, you can bind keyboard shortcuts to the conversion commands by going to **Window > Preferences > General > Keys** and filtering using "delimiter":
[image: binding a shortcut to EOL conversion]

Comment: Thank you, but I know about that command. I have to use it regularly. Problem is that I can notice wrong line endings only after commit. And that's difficult to fix then.

Comment: You might be able to use the solutions listed here to automate this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012230/eclipse-on-save-execute-a-program

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - try enabling 'General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters'  setting and set visibility to '70' or so; as a plus you will now be able to see tabs/spaces formatting at a glance.

Answer (score 39):

In Eclipse, to convert the line endings for existing files:

1. Go to the file browser view, and click on the project/folder/file that you wish to convert.
2. From the menu bar, select File > Convert Line Delimiters To > Windows / Unix / MacOS 9.

[image: Eclipse: Convert Line Delimiters To]

Comment: this converts through your file structure starting at the resource selected on your Package Explorer,
If you select a file, just that file will be converted, but if you select a folder a new windows will pop-up for you to refine your selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can Search your resources with the `Search`-Dialog and go to the tab `File Search`. There you can enter a Regular expression. Enter `\r\n` or whatever line ending you want to change.

Then hit the `Replace ..` Button instead of `Search`.

> I want just setup once and be sure that all line endings are in the same format.

... ok, my answer does not consider this.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* get usefull results with Eclipse save actions: If the eclipse formatter also converts the EOL style, you could use it to modify EOL style only for the files you are modifying.

Unfortunately I don't have eclipse here, so I can't test if this actually works. Worth a try, however.

Comment: This is an interesting point, however I don't like to use eclipse formatter on the whole file. It produces non nice code sometimes...