# SVN files difference ANSI-UNIX vs. ANSI-PC

Tags: svn, encoding, repository, tortoisesvn

I made some copy/ paste of files between my local repo (Windows) and my server(linux), and now, when I commit the changes to the SVN repository with Tortoise SVN, it detects changes in most of the files, when I didnt modified them.

[image]

If i compare with a comparator, the only difference it detects is codification, ANSI-LINUX vs ANSI-PC.

[image]

Is there some easy way to unify (or ignore codification changes) in order to not commit to the repo the files I didin´t modified?

Answer (score 2):

As is commented in this post:

[Automatic EOL conversion in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003830/automatic-eol-conversion-in-eclipse/7019737#7019737)

I found a **solution** in **Eclipse**, a way to convert EOLs in all files.

```
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace
```

and

```
File > Convert Line Delimiters To ...
```

It´s not a svnTortoise solution but, it solved my problem for now, now I thinks the other people wich works in this repo, should do the same if they don´t have EOL encoding same as the repo.