# unnoticeable lesscss compiler in eclipse pdt

Tags: css, eclipse, less

I want to use a less compiler like dotless as eclipse builder. If I set the build option "Run the builder:" to "During auto builds", every 5-10 sec the builder is runing (thats ok) but it also ask me to save, instead of ignoring the unsaved files.

As workaround I activate the workspace-option "Save automatically before build" and bind Ctrl+S to "build all"

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To automatically transpile LESS to CSS in Eclipse, I explain two possible ways.

1. Using a Plugin
2. How to do it manually

(I edited this post after I wrote the plugin, so the manual way is the *old* way, that the original post contained over some time, which you may have seen here a while ago)

### Requirements

For either solution you need to install `node` and `lessc` (the less-compiler).

Installing `lessc` through `npm` with the following commands:

```
npm install -g less-compiler
npm install -g less
```

### 1. Install the Eclipse Transpiler Plugin

I wrote an eclipse plugin to handle transpiling in eclipse. Just install it and follow the instructions on the project readme to configure transpiling for your project.

-> https://github.com/gossi/eclipse-transpiler-plugin

### 2. Manually install a builder

I wrote myself a little shell script that runs `lessc` after every save on a .less file. However, eclipse keeps its own environment, thus no `%PATH` variables are available in eclipse. So, you need the full path to the `lessc` command, which you can find with `which lessc`:

```
$ which lessc
/usr/local/bin/lessc
```

Also, because `lessc` runs on a node environment:

```
$ head -n1 /usr/local/bin/lessc
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

You cannot run this directly, because eclipse doesn't know about your environment. You need to prepend the node command, to achieve a `lessc` call in eclipse:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

The shell script with the *full path* to `lessc` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/lessc css/*.less > css/*.css
```

You may adjust the input and output sources according to your project. In order to make that run in eclipse we need to make it run as a builder. Here you go:

1. Rightclick on your project > Properties > Builders.
2. Click New, choose Programm and give it a cool name
3. "Main" Tab

   - Location: Choose the shell script here
   - Working Directory: I choosed the project folder
4. "Refresh" Tab

   - [x] Refresh resources upon completion
   - [x] Specific resources
   - Click on "Specify Resources..."
   - Check the resources that you want to be refreshed after the compilation, typically the css files
   - Recursively include sub-folders depends on you and your project
5. "Build Options"

   - [  ] Allocate Console (uncheck, we want it silent, turn it on for debugging)
   - [x] Launch in Background
   - Run the Builder

     - [  ] After a "clean"
     - [x] During manual builds
     - [x] During auto builds
     - [  ] During a "clean"
   - [x] Specify working set of relevant resources
   - Click "Specify Resources..."
   - Choose the resources you want to compile, typically your .less files. A Note, don't select the folder with css files here, that gets refreshed after the build, anyway your eclipse might get catched in a never-ending-loop here. So .less files will be enough.

Now, open a .less file, do some changes and save. Open the compiled .css file - tada :)

Windows:

I think this will work on windows too, with an according .bat file.

Have fun

Comment: Sorry, I forget that. I installed it via npm. `npm install -g lessc`.

Comment: This works with one exception: it's compiling style.less to *.css rather than style.css. Is there a way to make it keep the name or am I missing something?

Comment: you may adjust the shell script to your needs. It's just running lessc as you would in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool to watch your LESS files and compile on change:

- OS X: [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/)
- Windows: [WinLess](http://winless.org/)

Comment: These are standalone programs, can they be integrated in eclipse?

Comment: No, not really integrated. You would still have to add your project to the program. But after that these programs will auto-compile the less file when you change it in eclipse.

Comment: How could you do that? I found no auto-compile option in WST/PDT.

Comment: Using one of these programs (LESS.app or WinLess) would work as follows:
-Add the LESS files of your project to the program.
-The LESS files will now be automatically compiled each time you save changes to the LESS file.