# Run an application automatically when saving files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mysql

I want to be able to run an application every time I save a files in a project in eclipse.

In my case I want to be able to run mysqldump to make database dump files (including schema) in the project directory so that it could be tracked by GIT

Answer (score 0):

There's an old thread that covers it this:
[Eclipse: On Save execute a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012230/eclipse-on-save-execute-a-program)

TL;DR: Make a builder to do it.  Its less a matter of doing something on "save" as it is when the program is automatically built, which in most cases should be the same thing.

It also covers making a simple plugin to do it but this is probably overkill

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do something like this:

1. Create an ant script that contains an  task for the command you want to run. Place it in your project
2. Right-click the project
3. Select `Builders` on the left
4. Click `New`
5. Select `Ant Builder` and press `Ok`
6. For `Buildfile`, use `Browse Workspace...` to find the script.
7. For `Base Directory` use `Browse Workspace...` to select the project directory
8. If the script modifies any resources in the project, switch to the `Refresh` Tab and select the affected resources/directories
9. Switch to the `Targets` tab - select the targets to run for each build phase
10. Switch to `Build Options` - choose the resources that should trigger the script