# run automatically a command script after file save

Tags: eclipse

I want to instruct eclipse (oxygen IDE) to run a cmd-shell after I save a javascript file within a specified folder of my project. How can I do that with?

Are there any plugins for such kinds?

Comment: If you talking about the Eclipse Java IDE, see https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012281/2670892)

Comment: In the project properties dialog, select Builders, then click New...??? In eclipse oxygen no such menu dialog exist, I cannot find it.

Comment: Under "Run->Run configuration", I can create a build-file, which are executed successfully when I click the run-button afterwards. However, I want eclipse to trigger this script automatically after I save/edited a javascript-file. How can I do this?